# Return type issue in generic function using conditional type

Tags: typescript, generics, compiler-errors, intersection, conditional-types

I'm trying to create a generic function which takes a `FieldType` and returns an object containing the properties from a common base type as well as default values for that specific type of `FormField`. For some reason, I can't get this to work without the compiler complaining. I'm not sure where the problem lies but

I'm suspecting it might be the way the `FormField` type is defined as a conditional type. I've tried redefining my types in various ways without success so I'm suspecting I've either missed something obvious or maybe this isn't possible without type assertion.

Here are my types:

```ts
type FieldType = 'text' | 'number' | 'custom'

interface FormFieldBase {
  type: FieldType
  label: string
  error: string
  disabled: boolean
}

interface CustomField extends FormFieldBase {
  value: string
}

interface TextField extends FormFieldBase {
  value: string
  placeholder: string
}

interface NumberField extends FormFieldBase {
  value: number
}

type FormField<T extends FieldType> = T extends 'text'
  ? TextField
  : T extends 'number'
  ? NumberField
  : CustomField
```

And here are my generic functions:

```ts
const createBaseField = <T extends FieldType>(
  type: T
): FormFieldBase => ({
  type,
  label: '',
  error: '',
  disabled: false
})

const defaultValues: {
  [K in FieldType]: Omit<FormField<K>, keyof FormFieldBase>
} = {
  text: {
    value: '',
    placeholder: ''
  },
  checkbox: {
    value: false
  },
  custom: {
    value: ''
  },
  number: {
    value: 0
  }
}

const fieldCreator = <T extends FieldType>(type: T): FormField<T> => ({
  ...createBaseField(type),
  ...defaultValues[type]
})
```

---

The `fieldCreator` yields the following error:

> Type '{ type: FieldType; label: string; error: string; disabled: boolean; } & { number: Pick<NumberField, "value">; text: Pick<TextField, "value" | "placeholder">; checkbox: Pick<...>; custom: Pick<...>; }[T]' is not assignable to type 'FormField'.ts(2322)

In my mind, the intersection of `FormFieldBase` (from `createBaseField`) and the fields from `FormField<T>` excluding the fields from FormFieldBase (from `defaultValues`) should be `FormField<T>`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;**

`FormField<T>` as the proclaimed return type of the `fieldCreator` function knows nothing about `Defaults<FieldType>`.

**Longer version**

Note that your `FormField<T>` type only guarantees that the resolved type is either `CustomField`, `TextField`, or `NumberField`. All three `extends` the `FormFieldBase` type, so it is also guaranteed that the type conforms to the shape of `FormFieldBase`, but *nothing else*.

Now, your `fieldCreator` function signature proclaims that it returns a `FormField<T>`. Let's remove this explicit annotation and take a look if this is the case:

```ts
const a = fieldCreator("text"); //& Pick<TextField<"text">, "value" | "placeholder">
```

The `FormFieldBase` type is omitted for brevity. As you can clearly see, the return type has additional info about its shape *not present* in `FormField<T>`. As you correctly guessed, this info is taken from the `Omit<FormField<K>, keyof FormFieldBase>` because of the [spread properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) operation.

Thus, when you explicitly say that the `fieldCreator` function returns `FormField<T>`, the compiler rightfully complains that this is not the case. Just remove the annotation and let the TypeScript do its job and infer the correct type:

```ts
const a = fieldCreator("text");
a.value; //string
a.placeholder; //string

const b = fieldCreator("number");
b.placeholder; //error
b.value; //number
```

---

An aside: if you use generics, go all the way - `FormFieldBase` should accept `FieldType` as a type parameter, as well as extending interfaces and the type of the default constants. See the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwCrmgXigcmBAD2BygB9cA7AVwFsAjCAJxPJwGMqBnYAexpwBQAuBXyMAZgEM20GD0Y14SZACFJnCAB5UUQvgrJOsBCnSQAfFADeAqFFCQAXFFS2oiSQ0TPujEQHM3JkZ5H2A-CkC7ZDhOT0QIZGc6Hh4EyQoBAF8hETEpGSgAYS5eRRNkbV0iCAMjJVMMSz1aw1h5cuU1DW1LGzsAN0lEKggwiMCc4VEmAuhUPQbKnRa642UzCGaatbkFJe6tVD63IZGxqF8AtzAPGQALNOQmceupvNnpaAA5WgZGJZVVZtJabbb6EEdA7qI4nQbDUbOaj0JjZIQOWRQipAnYgipgqDYFa4ox4PSCOwAfhci2xxzczmJENJyP%20FKg1N%20KIBdPMDOKpT4gPpAjYPAo3CgbEYEEk%20EOS0JUBxzPWjQsAAo3BjGQIAJTOPadFCHXqEywa-r2DAAGjcHi8zhwODtdmCoVwLrcMTidASSSgUkQGmyevRGCgABEIFIqIhgJwVa16vimkqrXYANoAaSgIhcAF1nAB5GhwYCaI2A7PmG1QADWEBAPHE7X2FVNNb5WQA3EIxRLgFBnrH4wA1BEQTjOaOjhOV1MWdPavTODNQM6Iz2uuxQW5fR4oF6etxZHccbh8NdueHnJ3ss9uVnH9ebi4ABlP2T7ovFkvEFRFDKcryEqSa7IuWwajqLh6uaUCWm4AB0KHSrK8owks0EYHqO4oUhI6SHGwATucnCZhiBahv2f5DpISoAcoQHofIGoAET4EQbF6n2khIW%20PZQAA9EJVyRAIfH7g8TxMIJIliYEv6DlAdAMYBwG8Iw7HPow3F9nQSFSRAh7PIwclCe6jACAZAnCUJOlAA).

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! I suppose `Defaults` doesn't need to be generic if we assume `T` is always going to be equal to `FieldType`. Or any reason you did that?

Comment: @GustafLundström NP. Re:generic - well, it is mostly for consistency - since you treat `defaultValues` as a mapped type (which are sort of functions over an original type), it made sense to me to make it generic (maybe even generalize for reuse: `type GenericDefaults<T, E, B> = { [ K in T & string ] : Omit<E, keyof B>; }`).

Comment: Gotcha. Good suggestion.